# How Can Fix "run time error 3251" in excel VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, debugging, runtime-error, export-to-excel

I am using excel 2016., I used a form to fill data in access, but when click refresh I start getting "run time error 3251" on this one. If can someone help me to find out. please.

I am fetching data from access to excel VBA user form & then doing some updates & deleting as per requirement.

**Error**

> Msg=> "Run-time error '3251': Current Recordset does not support
> updating.    This may be a limitation of the provider, or of the
> selected locktype."

**Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    
    ''''''''Add Validation here '''''''''''''
     
       If IsDate(Me.txtdate1.Value) = False Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the correct Transaction_Date", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Me.txtcampany1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Campany", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
     
    If Me.txttrans1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Type_Transaction", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Me.txtdebit.Value <> "" Then
        If IsNumeric(Me.txtdebit.Value) = False Then
            MsgBox "Please enter the correct Debit", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    If Me.txtcredit.Value <> "" Then
        If IsNumeric(Me.txtcredit.Value) = False Then
            MsgBox "Please enter the correct credit", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    If Me.txtbank1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the By_Bank", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    
    If Me.txtStuff1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Stuff", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Me.Texremr1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Comment", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Me.Textdenu.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Deposits_Number", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
        
    End If
    
     If Me.Textattech.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Attchment_File", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Me.bra1.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Branch", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Me.depf.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter the Deposits_For", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
     
    
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        
    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim qry As String
           
    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database.accdb"
    
    If Me.txtId.Value <> "" Then
        qry = "SELECT * FROM Public_Deposits WHERE ID = " & Me.txtId.Value
    Else
        qry = "SELECT * FROM Public_Deposits Where ID = 0"
    End If
    
    rst.Open qry, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    
    If rst.RecordCount = 0 Then
        rst.AddNew
    End If
    
    rst.Fields("Transaction_Date").Value = VBA.CDate(Me.txtdate1.Value)
    rst.Fields("Campany").Value = Me.txtcampany1.Value
    rst.Fields("Type_Transaction").Value = Me.txttrans1.Value
    
    If Me.txtdebit.Value <> "" Then rst.Fields("Debit").Value = Me.txtdebit.Value
    If Me.txtcredit <> "" Then rst.Fields("credit").Value = Me.txtcredit
    rst.Fields("By_Bank").Value = Me.txtbank1.Value
    rst.Fields("Stuff").Value = Me.txtStuff1.Value
    
    rst.Fields("Comment").Value = Me.Texremr1.Value
    rst.Fields("Deposits_Number").Value = Me.Textdenu.Value
    rst.Fields("Branch").Value = Me.bra1.Value
    rst.Fields("Deposits_For").Value = Me.depf.Value
    rst.Fields("UpdateTimestamp").Value = VBA.Now
    rst.Update
  
    Me.txtdate1.Value = ""
    Me.txtcampany1.Value = ""
    Me.txttrans1.Value = ""
    Me.txtdebit.Value = ""
    Me.txtcredit.Value = ""
    Me.txtbank1.Value = ""
    Me.txtStuff1.Value = ""
    Me.Texremr1.Value = ""
    Me.Textdenu.Value = ""
    Me.bra1.Value = ""
    Me.depf.Value = ""
           
    MsgBox "Updated Successfully", vbInformation
    
    Call Me.List_box_Data
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the file on a read only drive?

Comment: Why use Excel for interface and not a bound form in Access?

Comment: Is it _Campany_?